# React Material-Table how to pass rowData argument?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have been trying to use material-table for react, my code grabs the data from the API and then I have to open a Popup window that will call another API, and for that I would need the rowData.ID_value_to_call.

For now I'm simply trying to see the rowData but I can't seem to find the right syntax, as I keep getting "rowData' is not defined  no-undef".

Code for Material-Table here:

```
<MaterialTable
            columns = {columnsSetup}
            options={{
                showTitle: false, 
                search: false,
                filtering: true
            }}

            onRowClick={(console.log(rowData))} <----- issue right here

            data={query =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let url = GET_ORDERS_URL
                url += 'qtt=' + query.pageSize
                url += '&page=' + query.page
                console.log(url);
                fetch(url)
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(result => {
                    resolve({
                      data: result.data,
                      page: result.page,
                      totalCount: result.totalElems
                    });
               })
           })
         }
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onRowClick` has a signature of `(event, rowData)`. See the description on this page: https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

So, change it to:

```
onRowClick={(event, rowData) => console.log(rowData)};
```

this is a valid function with the required signature. Your current code is calling the `console.log` function directly instead of passing a function that can be called when the row is clicked.